# ExtJS button handler not working

Tags: extjs, scope

My ExtJS button's handler is not invoked after clicking. Now the code looks like this.

```
Ext.define('EDS.view.selector.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.selectorcontainer',

    title: 'Selector_V2',
    renderTo: 'input-div',
    layout: 'fit',
    height: '100%',

    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                defaults: {
                    bodyPadding: 10
                },
            }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Reset',
            handler: function(){
                console.log("Reset");
                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Add to constrain',
            handler: this.addConstrain,
        }
    ],

    /*
     * Logic for button "Add to constrain"
     * 
     * Adds an entry into the constrain list describing a person, cost center or an application
     */
    addConstrain: function(button, event){
        console.log('Add_to_constrain clicked');
    }
});
```

Originally this 'selectorcontainer' was put diretly in my app.js. But I extracted it into a stand-alone view. Before the extraction, it works perfect but now it is not working.

BTW, I've two buttons and the first "reset" works fine. So I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with "this.addConstrain" related to scoping.

Comment: You should clean up your trailing commas, otherwise this will break in some browsers.

Comment: Good point. I'll do that after the development completes. Is there any 3rd party tools on that? @Towler

Comment: I haven't come across any, but I haven't looked too hard either.  If you find one, let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to design your class is like this. You apply your config settings to the object before you do the callParent.

```
Ext.define('EDS.view.selector.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.selectorcontainer',

    title: 'Selector_V2',
    renderTo: 'input-div',
    layout: 'fit',
    height: '100%',

    initComponent: function() {

        Ext.applyIf(this, {

           items: [
               {
                   xtype: 'tabpanel',
                   defaults: {
                      bodyPadding: 10
                   }
               }
           ],
           buttons: [
               {
                  text: 'Reset',
                  scope: this,                 // <--- scope to form panel
                  handler: function(){
                     console.log("Reset");
                     this.getForm().reset();
                  }
               },
               {
                   text: 'Add to constrain',
                   scope : this,               // <--- scope to form panel
                   handler: this.addConstrain
               }
           ]
       });

       this.callParent(arguments);

  }
  /*
   * Logic for button "Add to constrain"
   * 
   * Adds an entry into the constrain list describing a person, cost center or an      application
   */
   addConstrain: function(button, event){
      console.log('Add_to_constrain clicked');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You're right, it is a scoping issue -  `this` is not the class you're defining; it's the scope  at the time the `Ext.define` function is called (likely `window`).  There are a few ways to handle this.  The easiest (in my opinion) is to change your handler to work similarly to your reset handler:

```
{
    text: 'Add to constrain',
    handler: function(btn, e) {
       //'this' is now the button
       this.up('selectorcontainer').addConstrain(btn, e);
    }
}
```

You could also add the buttons as part of the `initComponent` function instead of defining them as part of the `Ext.define` config.

```
initComponent: function() {
    //'this' is now the selector container
    this.buttons = [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function(){
            console.log("Reset");
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Add to constrain',
        handler: this.addConstrain
    }];

    this.callParent();
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. I chose your second solution. It's a shame that I can not vote up more than one time

Comment: I prefer the first one because it makes the code a bit cleaner.  However, when I use it, I do "btn.up()…" instead of "this.up()…" for clarity.  That way I don't have to mess with scoping.

Comment: It is better to add: "scope: this," between "text: 'Add..." and "handler:..". Then the scope of the handler is pointing to the object where the button is child of.